# How to break the vicious cycle of test-writing preceding an initial release?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, foss, user-interaction

I'm developing a FOSS library which I am pretty fond of. More specific details probably don't matter.

I've already "finished" a feature set sufficient for an initial release IMHO. However - some of the features I introduced in there were added for completeness of the API; I didn't use them in my own applicative coding (which gave rise to the library), and they've never been tested at all. The ones I have used had only been tested through my use, which has not focused on questionable corner cases.

So here is the vicious cycle:

1. To be released, even initially the library code needs to be functionally correct and well-performing - if not perfectly, than at least to good degree.
2. To ensure correctness (not to mention performance), testing is necessary; at least, unit test coverage.
3. To be involved in writing and running tests for the library, and resolving issues which come up during testing (and they do naturally come up), people have to like it and be interested in it.
4. People won't get to know and perhaps become fond of the library before it's released (for some definition of release).

it's 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 and thus on and on in a vicious cycle.

So far, I've just spent quite some time just writing unit tests myself, and it seems this way I'll release when I'm retiring and the whole thing is irrelevant.

My question: How do I break this vicious cycle? Or in other words - how can I get some potential users into helping me with the annoying and somewhat boring work of writing and running unit tests (and perhaps resolving the issues that come up)?

---

<sub>**Edit:** I ended up writing the tests myself. It was "just" 108,849 different assertions... :-(</sub>

Comment: Nothing vicious about it. If it doesn't work, it won't get used. You don't know it works until you test it.

Comment: Just take an example code snippet from your docs and test that it works. You now have one integration test! Don't bother chasing code coverage with low-level unit tests, they have rapidly diminishing returns. Also, don't implement functionality unless it meets an actual, non-speculative need: useful software is generally better than beautiful, perfect software (but this depends on the application domain).

Comment: I think your post is abusive. Maybe a good first step would be to not insult your potential co-collaborators.

Comment: @MartinK: That was supposed to be humorous. I guess my joke wasn't being taken as such. See edit.

Comment: @einpoklum, that's the way I took the initial text, but unfortunately humor doesn't always translate well whether we're talking about native English speakers or not.

Comment: I took the freedom and removed some parts which probably caused the downvotes and distracted from your core question (which is IMHO a good one).

Comment: Very related: [How do I attract new programmers](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-do-i-attract-new-programmers) on Opensource.SE

Comment: See also: [Picking a Ship Date](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/04/09/picking-a-ship-date/) by Joel Spolsky.

Comment: Why would you add features you don’t use to this project ? I think that’s the main issue here. Let people add features they need along with tests.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: Suppose I was writing a library which draws shapes; and in my uses, a shape is either empty with a border or full with no border. Would I not design my library to support full shapes with a border?

Comment: Don't accept pull requests for the library if the proper tests are missing, simple as that

Comment: @einpoklum No you wouldn’t. Because the consumer is king. When someone (including you) would need full shapes with a border, they would implement it. The API and the design emerging from this need has way more chance to be on point, since it’d respond to this very use case. How many times have we all coded something in advance, only to see we forgot many things when actually using it. And if you end up choosing this path, where does it stop ? Why one border only ? Maybe I need to merge two shapes together. Maybe I want a 3D effect on those shapes.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: 1. There are no "consumers" here; libraries aren't for consumers, like retail-goods are (and even there I'm not sure about that phrase).3. The library will not atrract users if it has an incoherent API with just enough functionality to do exactly what I have been doing. No, you grow around what you've implemented for yourself to make something would be appealing to others. As for the need - I see and know what people are using right now, and basing myself on that. You could tell me to avoid more obascure functionality, I suppose.

Comment: "libraries aren't for consumers" - who are they for, then?

Comment: @AntP: Software developers.

Comment: @einpoklum software developers *are* consumers.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard: They don't consume anything. I mean, they don't consume software.

Comment: Why not publish the untested features as feature branches? "caveat developer"

Comment: @Caleth: 1. Because there hasn't been any publication of the existence of the library 2. Because most of the features are untested. 3. Because the library doesn't make sense without those features (or at least most of them).

Comment: @einpoklum: I guess this leads to nothing, you just ignore any advice given to you. And of course are developers who use your library in their software are consumers of your library. No offense, but you seem just unwilling to write unit test and have "more fun" writing actual code. Software developing is not just like that. Listen to what others said. Only add (and test) code you actually need, this will automatically prevent you from adding a lot of untested features

Comment: For example, you could/should apply the test-driven development (TDD). Before adding a new feature, you write unit tests for it (i.e. against interfaces or base classes). Then you start writing the code. This way you know exactly what you need and for **why** you need it, then you write the code.

Comment: This automatically slows down "feature development" since your test need to be written before you start and while you develop it, you always know you are on the right path or not (Red (test failed since not implemented) -> Green (feature working correctly) -> Refactor (now you refactor your code to be better readable and maintainable) -> Green (all tests pass after refactoring) )

Answer (score 8):

Open Source works best when there is a community behind the code.  That means getting people interested in it.  I would do a pre-alpha release and be really clear about the state of things.  I.e. what you are confident in, what you are not confident in.  Attempt to get people to start helping in the community.

As you build out the test suite (hopefully with the help of your community) to a level where you are confident in the API coverage, you can start beta releases.  And when you are finally assured that the release is stable and performant, you can do your first official release.

Bottom line is, **release early, release often**.  And drum up traffic for your project where ever is *appropriate*.  This is the start of building community.  The other part is not have the thing so polished that there is nothing left to do.

The release structure would be like this:

- SNAPSHOT -- you get what you get, no guarantee of stability or safety
- Alpha -- functionally complete, but could have serious bugs
- Beta -- should be free of serious bugs, and no guarantees of performance
- Release Candidate (RC) -- we think we are ready to do a real release, a way to make sure your release packaging is correct
- Final -- the community is happy to sign off on this release

Many communities do a daily SNAPSHOT release.  Each stage in the release structure represents a greater promise of stability and correctness.  (Hopefully) No one is going to assume that any given library is completely and utterly free of problems.  However, the care at which you take to put that final release seal on a particular version does reflect the level of confidence your users can have in your software.

---

On the testing aspect, if this is a library, test the API.  Test expected inputs, and expected error cases.  Use your unit tests for internal testing, but you need to build up a test suite for the API itself.

Comment: But what if the library is "mostly complete functionally, and rather likely to have serious bugs in the never-run, parts"? Is that still a "legit" alpha version to announce? Or a pre-alpha?

Comment: @einpoklum get rid of the never-run parts. E.g. run the tests with coverage, and delete (or at least be very skeptical about) anything that doesn't get hit. If that breaks something for you, write the tests for that. Don't focus on getting "mostly complete functionality" (whatever mostly and complete mean for this); focus on a well-tested core that does what you currently need well, because that's the requirement you best understand. Questionable corner cases are questionable; ignore them as long as you can.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Before I wrote the unit tests I have so far (which have taken months - since I don't have that much free time), over 70% of the library was never-run. But point taken about the questionable corner cases.

Comment: Perhaps use some form of sub-packaging. Place high-configence code in the "core", and layer out to your least-confident (probably just explode) code. The user then can choose "core", "beta", "alpha", etc...

Comment: @einpoklum, as long as you have significant (functional) parts of the library that are not tested in any way, not even by using them in a project, then the status of the project would not be above alpha. If you do call it alpha, be honest about the coverage status of each part (compiles / basic usage coverage / extensive test coverage / etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should look at [Technology adoption life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_adoption_life_cycle):

[image: Technology adoption life cycle]

For you, the innovators and early adopters are the most important groups.

Innovators are tinkerers. They play and try things. They don't care about things working, as they are often willing to fix the problems themselves. They are willing to take on risks of things not working on themselves. For them, not having tests is often not an issue.

It is only when you start getting into early adopters, where you start to need to maintain some level of quality. It is then that test automation becomes a good long-term investment. Before that, tests could very well be a liability that prevents you from quickly iterating new ideas and experimenting.

Early on, you should really focus on figuring out if your solution is actually something that is useful for people and solves actual problem. Way too often, people create a solution and then have hard time finding actual problem to solve. If you truly have a solution for a problem people will, innovators will use it and will give you feedback or even help to improve the quality by helping you with tests.

Answer (score 2):

> it's 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 and thus on and on in a vicious cycle

It's not a vicious cycle. It has a very clear starting point: **you wrote the code**.

If you wrote the code, then it stands to reason you understood its purpose. If you understand its purpose, then you can write tests.

Testing is nothing more than checking to see if the written code fulfills the purpose it was written to fulfill.

If you don't know what the purpose of the features is, then you don't need them. It's as simple as that.

If you can explain to me exactly why you actually need the features, then you are inherently explaining to me what their purpose is, and you can write tests for that exact purpose.

A simple example of what I mean:

***einpoklum**: I can't test this feature.*
***Flater**: Why?*
***einpoklum**: I don't know what to test.*
***Flater**: Then you don't need the feature. Scrap it.*
***einpoklum**: I can't, because users will want this feature because it [sanitizes their input].*
***Flater**: So write a test to see if the feature correctly [sanitizes the input].*

---

> and the ones I have used were only tested through my use, which has not focused on questionable corner cases

Expecting your unit tests to catch every conceivable corner case is an unreasonable standard. You're going to forget things and that's perfectly normal. If you feel like you wrote the necessary tests, then you're good to go.

Should you stumble on a bug with an uncovered corner case, simply fix the bug and write a test that will (in the future) ensure that any regression will be flagged as a test failure.

Of course there is a reasonable line to draw on how many tests you write in the beginning, but that line is both subjective (to the developer) and contextual (to the use case). There is no universally correct line here.

Especially for FOSS, it's perfectly acceptable to cover only common cases and obvious corner cases.

---

The question is built on three premises:

1. I don't want to release untested code
2. I want to release
3. I don't want to write the tests

There is a clear contradiction here. You can pick any two and it's fine, but the third will always cause contradictions.

Comment: I didn't say I can't test, or that I don't know what to test. I can and I do. But implementing unit tests for a library with a large API and short implementations can take much much longer than writing that library. That being said - point taken regarding not trying to catch the corner cases initially.

Comment: @einpoklum: By writing the code, you knew what the expected public behavior of the code was going to be, and therefore you can write tests against it. If you don't want to test, you can still release, but the volatility increases. You hold 3 opinions that conflict: (A) I don't want to release untested code (B) I want to release (C) I don't want to write the tests. You have have 2 out of 3, no more.

Comment: Is the question, "how can I have tests without writing tests?"

Answer (score 1):

It is **highly unlikely** you will ever get anybody to write unit-tests for your code for free - even if they like your library and find it useful.

Think about why you don't write the tests yourself: You find it "boring and annoying". Nevertheless, you are the one who have the most to gain from the unit-tests *and* they are much easier for you to write than for anybody else, since you implemented the functionality. Not many people find it fun to write unit tests for code they didn't write themselves.

I suggest you either remove the functionality which you don't use (following the YAGNI principle), or adopt a test-driven development approach.

Comment: Nitpick: A "test-driven development approach" is more relevant to applications or implementations of an agreed API than to the case where the API design is a significant part of what the library is. But of course - that's part of the specifics I hadn't gotten into.

Comment: More to the point, though - I want to find a way to lighten the load, not transfer it to someone else. There are thousands of testcases. I'm spending time just writing some generic code for kinds of testcases so that I can define more test cases generically.

Comment: @einpoklum: You should probably update the question to make that clear then.

Comment: @einpoklum *"more relevant to applications or implementations of an agreed API"* - that's not true at all. TDD allows you to explore what the API should be *by writing the tests*, giving you at least one consumer of the API before it even exists (which is the cheapest time to change it).